# Enabling Axis 2 Debug Log on Jboss

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, apache-axis

I would like to know how can I enable debug-level logging with Axis 2 on JBoss. My web service is installed as an .aar file in the Axis 2 web application. I have tried to add the following to jboss-log4j.xml:

```
<category name="org.apache.axis2">
         <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
```

But this didn't add anything to the server.log file. I have read it in many places that Axis2 stacks the logs in a file called axis2.log which can be found in the working directory of Axis2, but I didn't quite understand what's "Axis 2's working directory" ?

I would also like to know how to enable logging on an Axis 2 client which should tell me how Axis is serializing and deserializing requests/responses. How can I achieve that? I read it somewhere that I should configure a client-conf.wsdd, but I didn't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the jboss-log4j.xml file found in the conf folder, and then restarting Jboss enabled the debug logs, which were appended to the server.log file in the log folder:

```
 <category name="org.apache.axis2">
         <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
```

Answer (score 0):

try editing the log4j.properties file which can find at the WEB-INF/classes folder. For client side you need to add a log4j.properties file to a class patch and set the properties accordingly.